# Did Jesus as told in the New Testament really exist?

Tags: historical-jesus

Why do historians say that there is no evidence that a historical Jesus existed? Furthermore they deduce that Jesus is a conglomeration of several mythical and/or pagan characters.

Here is a typical documentary which lays out those facts.

https://youtu.be/SNtF1-Y-JJM

Comment: Mainstream historians certainly do *not* believe that there is no evidence that a historical Jesus existed. See http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/did-jesus-live for a good overview

Comment: Related/duplicate: [What extrabiblical sources support the existence of Jesus in history?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4613/21576)

Comment: As stated, this question appears either to ask for an opinion or to be a duplicate of previous questions about evidence from the post-apostolic period.  It could possibly be a good question if you asked what are the views of modern historians on the existence of Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no authority on this subject, but having asked myself the same question and done my own research on it before, I've come to the conclusion that Jesus really did exist in some way. It's the majority scholarly consensus.

I myself am actually an atheist, and I was excited by the work of Richard Carrier, a prominent mythicist. But the more I looked into it, it seemed that his arguments don't hold water.

I can't give you a great deal of detail on this; I didn't write down anything I read about it. But I can tell you that Bart Ehrman is a prominent New Testament scholar and atheist who defended the historicity of Jesus against Carrier. Linked below is a lengthy blog post of his in response to one of Carrier's.

I hope this helps!

http://ehrmanblog.org/fuller-reply-to-richard-carrier/

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). And see also: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). The question you're answering will likely be closed as a duplicate. Also, as asked it is more opinion-based than this site generally allows. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Meanwhile, I hope you'll stick around and read some of the other questions here.